# Animation when switch grid view to list view - Flutter

Tags: animation, flutter, gridview

I want to have the animation like this when switch between grid view and list view. How can I do it in Flutter?

[image: ![Text](https://im3.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-3-d2131e9e11f0.gif)]

Comment: Please see https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/hero-animations i'm not sure if it will work for the same page. I assume you should surelly use the same `heroTag` for both `GridView` and `ListView` corresponding items

Comment: thanks @user8773560, but it does not work :'(

Comment: Have a look at https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sidekick - it's no longer maintained but it may still work. Even if it doesn't, you should be able to figure out how it works and customize it for your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Simply creating a ListView and a GridView, using a bool variable to determine which one to show, wrapping each child in a Hero, and when you want to switch, changing the value of the said bool variable and then pushing the same route works. See here:
https://dartpad.dev/05785dfd91a02e55d68a6cd086dcbf0b

Comment: This is sick and surprisingly simple. Thanks!